# Bootstrap and rendering Arshaw Fullcalendar in a tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar

I am using Arshaw Fullcalendar with Bootstrap 3.0 and want to show the calendar in a tab - currently when I open the tab which has the calendar included I can only see the day/week/month/today etc buttons and upon clicking one of these the calendar renders.

According to http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/render/ I need add some code to tell the tabs to render the calendar when the tab is loaded.

I have tried adding this code to the same page as the tabs are loaded but it doesn't render and an error in the console of

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

showing under the line $('#myTab').tabs({

JS (I am already including jquery,fullcalendar.js and bootstrap.js)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTab').tabs({
            activate: function(event, ui) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="relative row block">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs margin_b_10 row block relative" id="myTab">
        <li class="active transition3 row block">
            <a href="#announcements" data-toggle="tab">
                <span class="circle_plus"><i class="icon-small icon-bubbles2"></i></span>
                <br>Announcements
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="transition3 row block">
            <a href="#calendar-tab" data-toggle="tab">
                <span class="circle_plus"><i class="icon-small icon-calendar2"></i></span>
                <br>Calendar
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content medium_padding_class_2 text-left" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="announcements">
        <p class="color_silver row">
            Announcements text
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="calendar-tab">
        <p class="color_silver row">
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the calendar to render fully in the tab when it is clicked?

Comment: I notice that there's a typo where the #calendar div isn't closed, but the error seems to be pointing to the fact that you haven't initialized the calendar plugin before using render.  Do you have something like this somewhere before calling render:     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    });

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo but as you suspected it isn't the issue - yes the code for fullCalendar is called prior. It loads fine once I click on any of the fullCalendar buttons at the top like today, week, month, day etc so the calendar itself works fine but won't render without one of those buttons being clicked

Answer (score 6):

I found this issue too. Reading the documentation for the Tab widget http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs I found that I could use the last event dispatched by the widget

> shown.bs.tab (on the newly-active just-shown tab, the same one as for the show.bs.tab event)

which is sent after the tab is visible. This way this invocation of the **render** method is going to work because the parent HTML container element is already visible (no need to wait for an undefined amount of time hoping that the container is already visible).

My solution was using something like this:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem myself, internally the fullcalendar library checks if the element containing the calendar is visible before doing a full render by using this  `element.is(':visible')`  where element is the tag on which you are using the fullcalendar method.

The problem i had was that by the time the click event fired on the tab, the element itself was not visible and thus was still not rendering. To solve this i added a timeout until the element passed the confirmation and it worked like a charm. Try the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTab').tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            if( $('#calendar').is(':visible')){
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
            }
            else{
                //change 2000 for whatever works for you.
                setTimeout(function(){ $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');},2000);
            }
        }
    });
 });
```